# Cannot get form element while parsing web page

Tags: php, curl

I wanna parse specific web page, exactly i want to get captcha image to solve it using anticaptcha. But problem is when I try to get the content of that page the form with captcha just doesn't exist. I tried curl and file_get_contents but having some issue. Also i tried to send some headers but without results

Comment: That's a bit vague, can you show us some code examples?  Or are you saying you are trying to do Captcha with Curl...well that's not going to work as Captcha uses Javascript and most 'linux based solutions' won't work with it.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe form may generated by formbuilder with javascript if that's so hot to be then?

Comment: file_get_contents('http://example.com'); if i visit this page on browser I can see the form. but when I am parsing there is no nothing about form and captcha(

Comment: file_get_contents doesn't support Javascript, hence you cannot read a proper Captcha from it, which BTW is the intention of the Captcha designer

Comment: Is there any ways to solve this? ABout javascript i am not sure. Can u check it if I send u a link?

Comment: No, many companies put Captcha's to prevent people from using `file_get_contents` `curl` and `lynx` from scraping it.  It's a security feature.  I shouldn't say 'no' but there isn't a general tool for this.

Comment: As others have commented, the Captcha possibly relies on dynamic Javascript in a way that will not be replicated when you make a 'dumb' request with curl. You quite likely need to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or some other 'headless browser' (such as Google Chrome in headless mode).

Comment: You know I think it cannot be unparseable since i have this task as a test task in order to get job. that's why...

Comment: @Marat: If you haven't done so already, try opening the developer console in your browser, and then examining 1) the HTML source and 2) how the HTML DOM is updated using Javascript. (Developer console is F12 in Chrome and I think Mozilla as well.)
If you can figure out what Javascript is responsible for loading the captcha image, you can try emulating that using PhantomJS.

Comment: @Marat it's not impossible, but it is a lot of coding for something that does not exist at this time.  Also requires a lot of low level shell script stuff.  Lets just say lots of people here (myself included) want such a program.  However we don't have the time needed to make this. (It's a lot) I do not think this is a 'job getting question' this is a 'lets use a job seeker to do some really hard work for us'

Comment: I've already figure out with this. Thanks